# Populating Map with markers using Redux and React-Native-Maps

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-maps

Can anyone recommend me some articles / docs or (better yet) tutorials on how to use Redux with React-Native-Maps?

Answer (score 0):

Found a good example on GitHub. They're using `React Native`, `Redux` and `react-native-maps`

https://github.com/mbeaudru/react-native-sample

No tutorials or articles found...